# Using a service worker to get list of files to cache from server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, service-worker

I´m trying to use a service worker in an existing asp mvc app. Generally, it´s working fine: I can cache files and so on. Problem is, that there are many files to be cached and I´m trying to return an array of paths to the service worker, so that the files can be added to cache without adding them manually.

Here´s what I have so far:

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetFilesToCache()
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(@"~\Content"), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        string[] cuttedFiles = new string[filePaths.Length];
        int i = 0;

        foreach (var path in filePaths)
        {
            cuttedFiles[i] = path.Substring(path.IndexOf("Content"));
            i++;
        }

        return Json(new { filesToCache = cuttedFiles }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This gives me a string array with entries like "Content\image1.png" etc.

Service worker:

```
    self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
    e.waitUntil(
            caches.open(cacheName).then(function (cache) {
            console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');

            return fetch('Home/GetFilesToCache').then(function (response) {
                return response;
            }).then(function (files) {
                return cache.addAll(files);
            });      
    })
  );
});
```

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Iterator getter is not callable.
```

Calling the action works just fine, data is received by the service worker, but not added to cache.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code:

```
return fetch('Home/GetFilesToCache').then(function (response) {
    return response;
}).then(function (files) {
    return cache.addAll(files);
});
```

the value of the `files` parameter is going to be a `Response` object. You want it to be the [JSON deserialization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) of the `Response` object's body. You can get this by changing `return response` with `return response.json()`, leading to:

```
return fetch('Home/GetFilesToCache').then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function(files) {
    return cache.addAll(files);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn´t work:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Iterator getter is not callable.

Comment: Setting a breakpoint at .then(function(files)) revealed that files is an array with 84 elements, which I expected it to be. But I don´t know why that error message comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with this code:

```
    self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function (cache) {
            console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');

            return fetch('Home/GetFilesToCache').then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function (files) {
                var array = files.filesToCache;
                return cache.addAll(array);
            });      
    })
      );
    });
```

Notice: 
Chrome only lists a part of files stored in cache, so you just have to click that little arrow to show the next page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
return fetch('Home/GetFilesToCache').then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function(files) {
    return cache.addAll(files);
});
```

The returned file has "filesToCache" property on "files" and also use "add" instead of "addAll".

So you need to write the following way.

```
return fetch('Home/GetFilesToCache').then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function(files) {
    return cache.add(files.filesToCache);
});
```